# Data Table refresh data when Modal query is submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the filtered table. When I clicked the modal then close it, this will return to default data.

How to return to current filtered data in datatable even if refresh or submitted on a modal.
[When click returns a modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNk1c.png)

When close or submit it will refresh to default data and not the filtered ones.

Comment: It depends on the way you actually modify your data - it's either re-load the data from the backend ([`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())) or simply re-draw ([`.draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())) if changes are done locally on the client-side.

Comment: I already use ajax reload but it somehow goes to default table not the filtered table

Comment: Yeah, now I see that in your code.